# Multiple images update laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two related tables where one is a `products` table and the other a one a `products_photos` table. In the `products_photos` table there are the columns `id`, `product_id` and `filename`. I'm trying to edit multiple images when editing a product. The error I'm getting is

> Method `Illuminate\Http\Request::photos` does not exist.

How can I edit multiple images at once?

This is how I create multiple images:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{ 
    foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
        $filename = $photo->store('public/photos');
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    } 
    return redirect()->back(); 
}
```

This is how I edit multiple images:

```
$image = Product::with('ProductsPhoto')
    ->where('id', $request->product_id)
    ->first();

if($request->photos('photos')) {
    if(file_exists($image ->photos)){
        unlink($image ->photos);
    }
    $filename = $photos->store('public/photos');
    ProductsPhoto::create([
        'product_id' => $product->id,
        'filename' => $filename
    ]);
} else {
    $image = $photos->store('public/photos');
}

$product = Product::with('ProductsPhoto')
    ->find($request->product_id);

$product->filename = $product->ProductsPhoto[0]->filename;
$product->save();
```

**Blade template:**

```
<input multiple="multiple" name="photos[]" type="file">
```

Comment: Share the snippet that shows the eloquent relationship between your Product model and ProductPhoto

Comment: Do you mean the relations? @Henry

Comment: Yes @joh. And I just noticed in your code, you did this:

$request->photos('photos')

What did you mean?

Comment: I have updated the question with models @Henry

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `$request->photos('photos')`. There is no **"photos"** method for the Request Class.

I think you wanted to do:

```
if($request->hasFile('photos')) {}
```

or

```
if($request->has('photos')) {}
```

Also, from your snippet:

```
$image = Product::with('ProductsPhoto')->where('id',$request->product_id)->first();
...

if(file_exists($image ->photos)){
    unlink($image ->photos);
}
```

the variable $image is a Product object, and there is no **photos** column in your table, so **$image->photos** will always be null. Rather, I think you meant to loop through `$image->ProductsPhoto` and get the `$each->filename`.

But I must say, there are lots of bugs within your code-base I'd suggest you really debug it:

- You are not looping through the multiple files in the update
- Are you trying to replace all previous images (if there were 3 images previously and now, I send two, do you want the 3 gone and replaced with the new two?). Because that is also not very clear.

amongst others.

Comment: So I'm getting this error `Unknown column 'filename'` it comes  from this line `$product->filename = $product->ProductsPhoto[0]->filename;` @Henry

Comment: Yeah, I want to replace the images so if I add two and there was 3 before, I want those 3 to be replaced @Henry

Comment: I have edited as you suggested but it shows an error `"Undefined variable: photos"` from the line below `else` statement `$image = $photos->store('public/photos');`  and I tried to comment that line and I got another error `Unknown column 'filename'` from this line `$product->filename = $product->ProductsPhoto[0]->filename;` you can see the edits from the question @Henry